# prerender io setTimeout does not work as expected

Tags: prerender

I am trying to use `prerender.io` and my problem is `setTimeout` function is executed without any delay or timeout.

Normal

```
setTimeout(function(){
//stuff
},300)
```

does not work either.

Comment: setTimeout works perfectly fine with Prerender.io. From the email you sent me it sounds like that's not being executed in your code.

Comment: No I do not mean it is executed, it will execute but without the timeout. For example the above code or stuff inside should run after 300ms but it is running immediately.

Comment: I've verified that the timeout is working as expected with Prerender.io. Email me the code you are running so that I can look into it. todd@prerender.io